# Show/Hide panels in ASP.net C# after submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, panel

So in the process of combining my default.aspx form page with the confirm.aspx confirmation page, I had to create panels and show/hide them at the initial loading of the page.

The form is a comment/complaint form, so users will submit their info, and an e-mail is generated and sent to a web master.

I have 4 panels: Panels 1 + 3 show by default and are set to visible early in the script like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Panel2.Visible = false;
    Panel3.Visible = true;
    Panel4.Visible = false;
}
```

Basically, I want panels 1+3 to become hidden, and 2 + 4 to become visible once the user submits the form and no errors are found within the forum.

Would I run the script to change the visibility at the `try` function when an email is sent, or right before the `frmReset` function?

Also, is there a specific function I need that will switch the panels visibility AFTER submitting the form with no errors found? (Other than changing visibility to `true` or `false`)

Comment: what are the functions you mentioned (try and frmReset)? That said, shouldn't you redirect the user to a confirmation page rather than playing with visibility ?

Comment: @SteveB The page used to redirect to another confirmation page, but I'm an intern and being tasked with doing this for learning purposes :P The `try` function runs `client.Send(objMail);`, and the `frmReset` is simply the reset button for the form.

Comment: You have provided two choices.  Why not just try both?  That will tell which (or if neither/both) of these locations is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Whoops, looks like I forgot to ask a part of my question; edited main post.

Comment: No, you don't need to do something other than change the `Visibility`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According your comments, you will resolve your requirement in two steps.

1st, update your page load to avoid reverting visibility after you change it :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack){
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
        Panel4.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

2nd, you have to change the visibility on the `try` method :

```
protected void Try_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    Panel2.Visible = true;
    Panel3.Visible = false;
    Panel4.Visible = true;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the first code update, I forgot about losing visibility after the submit. I still can't get the second code to run right; the page just loads back to itself after submitting the forum, and the panel visibility doesn't change. The email still functions after the form submit though.

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out. I was placing the `Panel1.Visible` functions in the wrong spot. Thanks for the help!