# show html table on button click of asp.net server control

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to display a table on the button click,right below the button,but it is getting display on the top of the page(Above the navbar).
This is what I did:

```
Response.Write("<table border='1' cellpadding='2'  WIDTH='20%' height='10px' style=\"margin-bottom:10px\">");
```

what should be done to align the table below the button?please help

Answer (score 0):

you should place a control and that add it into that control.
You can also take the help of html generic controls to add html control in the controls.

```
<asp:panel id="panel1" runat="server">
</panle>
```

and in code behind

```
panel1.InnerHtml="";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Response.write. Either:

1) Use some JavaScript and HTML to show/hide the table.

2) Use server side control for example

ASPX page

```
<asp:panel runat="server" id="foo" visible="false">
<table border='1' cellpadding='2'  WIDTH='20%' height='10px' style=\"margin-bottom:10px\>
....
<asp:panel>
```

Code

```
foo.Visible = true;
```

See [Show/Hide panels in ASP.net C# after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459914/show-hide-panels-in-asp-net-c-sharp-after-submitting-form)

Comment: In the html table I am displaying an sql database table. How to call the panel on button click?

Comment: see the link in my answer for an example

Comment: Yes I went through the link,but how do I display the sqlconnection part, the datafill and data adapter part in the pannel?

Comment: I have written the code for html table in the panel_load section,when the user clicks on the button,panle is visible and on page_Load I have set  Panel1.Visible = false; .. but still I am getting the same thing